# Convert float Series into an integer Series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following data frame:

```
In [31]: rise_p
Out[31]: 
         time    magnitude
0  1379945444   156.627598
1  1379945447  1474.648726
2  1379945448  1477.448999
3  1379945449  1474.886202
4  1379945699  1371.454224
```

Now, I want to group rows which are within a minute. So I divide the time series with 100. I get this:

```
In [32]: rise_p/100
Out[32]: 
          time  magnitude
0  13799454.44   1.566276
1  13799454.47  14.746487
2  13799454.48  14.774490
3  13799454.49  14.748862
4  13799456.99  13.714542
```

As explained above, I want to create groups based on time. So expected subgroups would be rows with times `13799454` and `13799456`. I do this:

```
In [37]: ts = rise_p['time']/100

In [38]: s = rise_p/100

In [39]: new_re_df = [s.iloc[np.where(int(ts) == int(i))] for i in ts]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-5ea498cf32b2> in <module>()
----> 1 new_re_df = [s.iloc[np.where(int(ts) == int(i))] for i in ts]

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How do I convert `ts` into an Integer Series since int() doesn't take a Series or a list as an argument? Is there any method in pandas which does this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try converting with astype:

```
new_re_df = [s.iloc[np.where(ts.astype(int) == int(i))] for i in ts]
```

**Edit**

On suggestion by @Rutger Kassies a nicer way would be to cast series and then groupby:

```
rise_p['ts'] = (rise_p.time / 100).astype('int')

ts_grouped = rise_p.groupby('ts')

...
```

Comment: Using `astype()` is definitely correct, but avoiding the list comprehension all together would be even better. Like `ts['time'] = (ts.time / 100).astype('int')` and then grouping with `ts.grouby('time')` and so on...

Comment: Yes agreed, avoiding the list comprehension would be much nicer, will edit my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different way to solve your problem

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
         time    magnitude
0  1379945444   156.627598
1  1379945447  1474.648726
2  1379945448  1477.448999
3  1379945449  1474.886202
4  1379945699  1371.454224

In [4]: df.dtypes
Out[4]: 
time           int64
magnitude    float64
dtype: object
```

Convert your epoch timestamps to seconds

```
In [7]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')
```

Set the index

```
In [8]: df.set_index('time',inplace=True)

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
                       magnitude
time                            
2013-09-23 14:10:44   156.627598
2013-09-23 14:10:47  1474.648726
2013-09-23 14:10:48  1477.448999
2013-09-23 14:10:49  1474.886202
2013-09-23 14:14:59  1371.454224
```

Groupby 1min and mean the results (`how=` can be an arbitrary function as well)

```
In [10]: df.resample('1Min',how=np.mean)
Out[10]: 
                       magnitude
time                            
2013-09-23 14:10:00  1145.902881
2013-09-23 14:11:00          NaN
2013-09-23 14:12:00          NaN
2013-09-23 14:13:00          NaN
2013-09-23 14:14:00  1371.454224
```

Comment: Thanx @Jeff! This approach looks good. Some methods are new to me. I'll give this a try. For now, I am gonna use the answer given by @drexiya.

Comment: Thanx @Jeff. I found this resource after posting the comment. So I had deleted the comment mentioning the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another quite general way to convert `ts` to a `Series` of type `int`:

```py
rise_p['ts'] = (rise_p.time / 100).apply(lambda val: int(val))
```

`apply` allows you to apply an arbitrary function to your `Series` object value by value. `apply` also works on columns of a DataFrame object.